# azure logic app request trigger url is not working from RestTemplate java but working in postman

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-logic-apps, resttemplate

I have Azure logic app with request trigger. I want to trigger this logic app from my java application. So, I am trying to call the request trigger url from my java API.

It is working fine if i am hitting in postman,
[logic app with request trigger hitting via postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aWPD.png)

but getting 401 on calling it using RestTemplate in java.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class SampleController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/display",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> display()
    {
        System.out.println("entered");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "https://pt-38.northeurope.logic.azure.com/workflows/cc0363a3bf134efca43b0bd2d15d5ed5/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=HnllGcN9xo91kRGAjk";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("api-version", "2016-10-01");
        headers.set("sp", "%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun");
        headers.set("sv", "1.0");
        headers.set("sig", "HnllGcN9xo91kRGAjk3Zlp6fW0dhwf");
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
//        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
//        System.out.println("obj");
        return response;
    }
}
```

[logic app with request trigger accessing via rest template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BECTW.png)

**As per Hury Shen suggestion i changed api code as below,**

```
public HttpEntity<String> display1()
    {
        System.out.println("entered");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "https://prod-38.northeurope.logic.azure.com/workflows/cc0363a3bf134efca43b0bd2d15d5ed5/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=HnllGcN9xo91kRGAjk3Zlp6fW0dhwfaRij-fk1CC60c";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                .queryParam("api-version", "2016-10-01")
                .queryParam("sp", "%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun")
                .queryParam("sv", "1.0")
                .queryParam("sig", "HnllGcN9xo91kRGAjk3Zlp6fW0dhwfaRij-fk1CC60c");
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                builder.toUriString(),
                HttpMethod.GET,
                entity,
                String.class);
        return response;
    }
```

Getting below exception,
[image: Exception in Postman]

Comment: Please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) (click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, we should put the value of `api-version`, `sp`, `sv` and `sig` in query parameters instead of put them in headers.

Do it like this:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("api-version", "xxxx");
params.put("sp", "xxxxx");
params.put("sv", "xxx");
params.put("sig", "xxxxxxx");
.....
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class, params);
```

Comment: I have added the latest result after changing api as per your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @ganthota Since you have added the parameters in code, so please change the `url` from `String url = "https://prod-38.northeurope.logic.azure.com/workflows/cc0363a3bf134efca43b0bd2d15d5ed5/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=HnllGcN9xo91kRGAjk3Zlp6fW0dhwfaRij-fk1CC60c";` to `String url = "https://prod-38.northeurope.logic.azure.com/workflows/cc0363a3bf134efca43b0bd2d15d5ed5/triggers/manual/paths/invoke";` in your code.

Comment: I changed the URL as you suggested getting below error,
"message": "401 Unauthorized: [{\"error\":{\"code\":\"AuthorizationFailed\",\"message\":\"You do not have permissions to perform action 'run' on scope '/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/'. Verify you are making the request with the appropriate HTTP method. See http://aka.ms/logic-trigger for details.\"}}]",

Comment: @ganthota Please change the code from `.queryParam("sp", "%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun")` to `.queryParam("sp", "/triggers/manual/run")`